# Why is my android device resetting itself?

Tags: android

I have a SEMC X10 Mini Pro, which has a tendency to randomly reset itself for no apparent reason.

I would like to inspect the Android system log file just prior to the reset, however I am unsure how to do this.

I have tried the app "Log Collector", however, the logs produced by this app only contain information from the last start-up, ie they don't contain the logging I'm interested in - before the "last start-up", around the "last shutdown".

Any advice out there?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably get better luck on Android Stack Exchange, unless you are looking to do this programmatically. In which case [take a look through the Log Collector source code](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/source/browse/trunk/android-log-collector/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/SendLogActivity.java) and see if you can modify it to save you a txt file that will persist through a restart so you can go back through it once the device is rebooted.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/ is very good, thanks